# Non-zero elements of skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, number-theory, integers

Let $A \in \mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ be an integer-valued skew-symmetric matrix. Is there an equivalent matrix $A' \in \mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb{Z})$, s.t. the number $m$ of non-zero entries is minimal (so $m$ is an invariant)? If so, is this minimal set of non-zero entries itself unique? How can they be determined?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the question "is this minimal set of non-zero entries itself unique?"

Comment: Also, what does it mean to you for matrices to be "equivalent"?

Comment: I wondered, whether there is a unique matrix $A' \sim A$,s.t. the number of non-zero entries is minimal. By equivalent, I mean that there are unimodular matrices $S,T$, s.t. $A'=SAT$.. (actually I'm not sure if I need similarity here)

Comment: **Note:** A matrix that is *equivalent* to a skew-symmetric matrix need not be skew-symmetric itself.  The same is true for similarity.

Comment: It seems obvious to me that such a matrix $A'$ will not be unique: it will probably suffice to take $S$ and $T$ to be permutation matrices (of permutations with even parity).

Comment: That is why I required it above.. sorry if that was misleading

Comment: yes, so I meant up to permutations, that is why I said that the set of entries (up to sign) should be unique in the first place

Comment: Oh, I see now.  Thanks for clarifying.